Trouble Restoring DB/Logs to point in time
I am trying to use SSMS to restore a database to a specific point in time. When I select the point in time, I get 3 backup sets to restore, one of them with a null filename and location.
The script is outlined below, and there is a failure stating

Cannot open backup device 'NUL'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) for the log restore of RESTORE LOG [dbRestore] FROM DISK = N'NUL' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5, STOPAT = N'2024-05-10T13:48:38'

I cannot figure out why this is happening and why SSMS is doing the NUL file.
USE [master]

BACKUP LOG [db] TO DISK = N'X:db_LogBackup_2024-05-13_14-44-13.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'db_LogBackup_2024-05-13_14-44-13', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, NORECOVERY , STATS = 5

ALTER DATABASE [dbRestore] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE [dbRestore] FROM DISK = N'X:\UserDB\db\db_backup_2024_05_10_020001_7961349.bak' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'db' TO N'F:\dbRestore', MOVE N'db_log' TO N'L:\dbRestore', NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5

RESTORE LOG [dbRestore] FROM DISK = N'X:\UserDBLogs\db\db_backup_2024_05_10_020357_8311872.trn' WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5

RESTORE LOG [dbRestore] FROM DISK = N'NUL' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5, STOPAT = N'2024-05-10T13:48:38'

ALTER DATABASE [dbRestore] SET MULTI_USER

GO

Tried restoring to point in time and expected the database to restore to that point in time. Tried restoring to a different point in time and had the same issue.

To pick up on Erik's comment: for instance the backup product Veeam does a log backup to NUL before producing its snapshot backup of the machine, by default. The reasoning behind this is to assist up with emptying the log, I imagine. The behaviour can be changed.

VEEAM is doing the NUL backup. I tried running the command below as recommended and it leaves the database in recovery and inaccessible. If I run RESTORE DATABASE DB WITH RECOVERY it reverts the transaction logs.

RESTORE DATABASE [dbRestore] FROM  DISK = N'X:\UserDB\db\db_backup_2024_05_10_020001_7961349.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'db' TO N'F:\dbRestore',  MOVE N'db_log' TO N'L:\dbRestore',  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
RESTORE LOG [dbRestore] FROM  DISK = N'X:\UserDBLogs\db\db_backup_2024_05_10_020357_8311872.trn'  WITH  FILE = 1,   RECOVERY, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,  STOPAT = N'2024-05-10T13:36:44'

Thanks for the help on this. I was able to restore the logs from VEEAM and perform the recovery which was cumbersome. Moving forward I have the following enabledf you select “Truncate logs” inside the SQL tab then Veeam will perform a log backup to the file name
“nul” after the snapshot was produced. It will do this for all databases that are in full or bulk logged
recovery model. This will render your own log backups performed after this useless. So, to avoid this,
choose “Do not truncate logs.”
